# Pyautogui screenshot & schedule not correct

Tags: python, timestamp, scheduled-tasks, screenshot, pyautogui

I have the below code saved down as a Python script which I have scheduled in Windows to run at specific times - 12:15 am and 5:15 am.

```
import pyautogui
from PIL import ImageGrab
from functools import partial
from datetime import datetime

myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()

myScreenshot.save(datetime.now().strftime("screeenshot_%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M.jpeg"))

exit()
```

Now I can see in Windows Scheduler that the task has been run, and the files created are created at the correct time, but the actual screenshot itself doesn't show the correct time in the taskbar, meaning that it's taking the screenshot at the wrong time?
This is windows scheduler

[image: windows scheduler]

I can see the files created have the right name and timestamp too, so not sure why the actual screenshot is taken at a different time?

[image]

On the actual screenshot, 1st has the correct timestamp in windows taskbar

[image: screenshot1]

On second screenshot, you can see it's not 5:15am. This one is taken at the wrong time?

[image: screenshot2]

Could someone please tell me why this happens?

In summary, screenshot 1 at 12:15 am runs correctly and gives me the correct output. Screenshot 2 at 5:15 am shows the right filename, timestamp on the file, but the actual screenshot seems to be taken at a different time - 4:45 am?